# Which device name I should use when I want to add one disk into my RAID5 array with mdadm?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I want to add one more hard disk into my RAID5 array. But I found there are many device names in the ubuntu file system which are the MD devices I could config. Now I list them as following:

> 1. /dev/md127
> 2. /dev/md126
> 3. /dev/md126p1
> 4. /dev/md/imsm0
> 5. /dev/md/RAID5
> 6. /dev/md/RAID5p1

I know that the last 3 files are symbolic links to the first 3 files. But I still don't know which device file name in the first 3 files I should choose in the mdadm command as the following?

> mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sda

or

> mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sda

or

> mdadm --add /dev/md126p1 /dev/sda

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've checked the 3 device files, they are exactly same. But I dare not to do any change on any one of them now. Because I fear this will damange the whole file system.

Comment: If you already have an existing array it will already have a name.  Run `sudo mdadm -D --scan` to show the array.

Comment: Terrance
I runed it as the following:
sudo mdadm -D --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm
ARRAY /dev/md/RAID5 container=/dev/md/imsm0 member=0 UUID=6cd482d5:21eec270:37f87ba0:b363865e

It displays two ARRAYs, but they are same, I don't fully understand why, and which one I should config, thanks!

Comment: The Intel array.  That one is a little more complicated.

Comment: So the name would be number 4 on your list.

Comment: It's same as /dev/md127, but /dev/md127 is not mounted in my file system. My FS is using /dev/md126p1, all these stuffs are so messy, and no any useful document to provide valuable explanation.

Comment: Let me see what I can find you.  I have actually had to recreate an array of one of these before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71480/discussion-between-clock-zhong-and-terrance).

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/994393/edit) your question and add in the output of `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md/imsm0`

Comment: Ok, Let me try it tomorrow, and update you. Tonight is too late for me, I go to sleep now. thanks ! Terrance

Comment: Terrance, I've runed on imsm0,but the system report  the following mistaks:

mdmon: /dev/sdb is attached to Intel(R) /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.4 RAID controller (0000:00:11.4),
    but the container is assigned to Intel(R) SATA RAID controller (0000:00:1f.2).
       Mixing devices attached to multiple controllers is not allowed.

In fact,I didn't attach /dev/sdb to any RAID. What should I do in next step, I'm really confused on what Intel's RAID suppor in the linux system, it mess up the system.